# ggforest returns error Error in `[.data.frame`(cbind(allTermsDF, coef[inds, ]), , c("var", "level", : undefined columns selected

Tags: r, survival, cox

I am using the ovarian dataset from the survival package using the following standard code:

```
ovarian$rx <- factor(ovarian$rx, levels = c("1", "2"), labels = c("A", "B"))
ovarian$resid.ds <- factor(ovarian$resid.ds, levels = c("1", "2"), labels = c("no", "yes"))
ovarian$ecog.ps <- factor(ovarian$ecog.ps, levels = c("1", "2"), labels = c("good", "bad"))

ovarian <- ovarian %>% mutate(age_group = ifelse(age >=50, "old", "young"))
ovarian$age_group <- factor(ovarian$age_group)

surv_object <- Surv(time = ovarian$futime, event = ovarian$fustat)

fit1 <- survfit(surv_object ~ rx, data = ovarian)
ggsurvplot(fit1, data = ovarian, pval = TRUE)

fit2 <- survfit(surv_object ~ resid.ds, data = ovarian)
ggsurvplot(fit2, data = ovarian, pval = TRUE)

fit.coxph <- coxph(surv_object ~ rx + resid.ds + age_group + ecog.ps, data = ovarian)
ggforest(fit.coxph, data = ovarian)
```

I'm able to plot the survival curves but for some reason I am getting the error below when trying to forest plot the cox hazard model with the 4 parameters

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(cbind(allTermsDF, coef[inds, ]), , c("var", "level",  : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Am I missing something? I got the code off the datacamp tutorial so it should be working. Would really appreciate any suggestions for a solution to this.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any issues with code execution and ggforest() nicely executed with the newest version of R (version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)). Versions of the other packages:
survival_3.2-3
survminer_0.4.7
ggpubr_0.4.0 What versions of the R and the packages do you have in your current R session?

Comment: I had the same problem, but I just recently updated survminer (0.4.8) and it was solved.

Comment: Update 2024-03-08: I encountered this problem and solved it by updating broom, survminer and ggsurvfit to the most up-to-date CRAN binary versions (macOS) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely due to broom version 0.7.0 which has been reported to cause that error with survminer ggforest, see [here](https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/pull/485). Hopefully survminer will be updated soon to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which resolved when I installed an older version of R (R version 3.6.3) then installed an older version of Broom (0.5.6).